# How can you splice together a string with link_to variables that have indices relative to the string in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter, indexing

I'm trying to take many posts with example text `"you can find other #apple #orchard examples at www.google.com and www.bing.com #funfruit"` and display the text to the user with URLs and #tags linking to their appropriate routes.

I have successfully done this with text that only contains any number of #tags, or a single URL, with the following code:

application_controller.rb

```
  def splice_posts(posts, ptags, spliced)
    # Build all posts as items in spliced, with each item an post_pieces array
    posts.reverse.each do |post| 
        tag_indices = [] 
        tag_links = [] 

        # Get post URLs: [{:url=>"www.google.com", :indices=>[209, 223]}]
        post_links = extract_urls_with_indices(post.text)
        # Save each as rails style link with indices


        # For each of the ptags associated with post 
        ptags.where(post_id:post.id).each do |ptag| 
            # Store hashtag's start/stop indices for splicing post 
            tag_indices.append([ptag.index_start, ptag.index_end]) 
            # Store hashtag links for splicing post
            tag_links.append(view_context.link_to '#' + ptag.hashtag, atag_path(Atag.find_by(id:ptag.atag_id).id), 
            :class => 'post_hashtag', :remote => true, :onclick => "location.href='#top'")
        end 

        # Create and store post as post_pieces in spliced
        # If there are no hashtags
        if tag_indices.length == 0 
            # And no links
            if post_links.length == 0
                spliced.append([post.text, post.id])
            # But links
            else
                spliced.append([post.text[0..post_links[0][:indices][0]-2], 
                view_context.link_to(post_links[0][:url], post_links[0][:url], target: "_blank"), 
                post.text[post_links[0][:indices][1]..-1], post.id])
            end


        # Elsif there is one hashtag
        elsif tag_indices.length == 1 
            if post.text[0] == '#' 
                spliced.append([post.text[2..tag_indices[0][0]], tag_links[0], 
                post.text[tag_indices[0][1]..-1], post.id]) 
            else 
                spliced.append([post.text[0..tag_indices[0][0]-2], tag_links[0], 
                post.text[tag_indices[0][1]..-1], post.id])
            end  

        # Else there are multiple hashtags, splice them in and store 
        else 
            # Reset counter for number of tags in this post
            @tag_count = 0 

            # If post begins with tag, no text before first tag
            if tag_indices[0][0] == 0 
                post_pieces = []
            # Else store text before first tag
            else 
                post_pieces = [post.text[0..tag_indices[0][0]-2]] 
            end 

            # Build core of post_pieces, splicing together tags and text
            tag_indices.each do |indice| 
                post_pieces.append(tag_links[@tag_count]) 
                post_pieces.append(post.text[indice[1]..tag_indices[@tag_count+1][0]-2]) 
                if @tag_count < (tag_indices.length-2) 
                    @tag_count += 1 
                else
                    # Do nothing
                end 
            end 

            # Knock off the junk at the end
            post_pieces.pop 
            post_pieces.pop 

            # Finish compiling post_pieces and store it in spliced
            post_pieces.append(tag_links[-1])
            post_pieces.append(post.text[tag_indices[-1][1]..-1])
            # Make last item in array post id for comment association purposes
            post_pieces.append(post.id)
            spliced.append(post_pieces)
        end                   
    end
  end
```

The spliced posts are then easily served in the view piece by piece:

```
<% @posts_spliced.each do |post_pieces| %>
     <%# Build post from pieces (text and hashtags), excluding last element which is post_id %>     
     <% post_pieces[0..-2].each do |piece| %>
        <%= piece %>
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that this implementation is convoluted to begin with, and trying to patch it with dozens of nested if/else statement to handle URLs seems like madness, as I'm suspecting that a more experienced software engineer/rails developer could enlighten me on how to do this with a fraction of the code.

To clarify I have the following variables already available for each post (with examples) :

```
post = 'some text with #tags and www.urls.com potentially #multiple of each.com'

post_urls = [{:url=>"www.urls.com", :indices=>[25, 37]}, {:url=>"each.com", :indices=>[63, 71]}]

post_tags = [{:hashtag=>"tags", :indices=>[15, 20]}, {:hashtag=>"multiple", :indices=>[50, 59]}]
```

I'm thinking that a more practical implementation might involve the indices more directly, but perhaps breaking the post into elements in an array is the wrong idea altogether, or perhaps there is an easier way, but before I spend a couple hours conceptualizing the logic and writing the code for another possible unideal solution, I thought I should see if someone could enlighten me here.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something important, I think you've overcomplicated things.

First, you split the string by spaces.

```
string = "whatever string typed in by user"
split_string = string.split
```

Then you map the split-string-array according to your requirements and join the results.

```
# create show_hashtag(str) and show_link(str) helpers

split_string.map do |str|
  if str.starts_with?('#')
    show_hashtag(str)
  elsif url_regexp.match(str) # you must define url_regexp
    show_link(str)
  else
    str
  end
end.join(' ')
```

You won't have to worry about positions of the text, tags, or links because `map` will take care of it for you.

Wrap all of that in a helper and in your view you could do the following:

```
<%= your_helper(string_typed_in_by_user).html_safe %>
```

Watch out for the user typing in HTML though!

Comment: Those map and split functions are exactly what I needed to know about! Shrunk the function 3x and allowed me to remove a lot of other unnecessary code involving the indices, while adding additional functionality! I'm almost a total noob- but at least now I'm two methods in my repertoire-less of a noob :D Thanks you so much for enlightening me!

Comment: I decided to still compile everything into an array and serve it piece by, so used `map!` instead of `map`, that way the site's still safe from html-injection, if that makes sense.

Comment: Minor correction: there is a difference between functions and methods. In Ruby, there aren't any functions - they're all methods. You should look this up.